# Reemplazar fragment por otro con boton

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo una aplicacion con un tablayout en la que en una de las pestañas se carga un fragment. Este fragment contiene un boton con el que se deveria cargar otro fragment que substituiera el anterior pero aunque utilizo `.replace` los fragments se superponen y el principal no desaparece:

**Fragmento principal cargado en la pestaña del tablayout**

```
public class TabPerfil extends Fragment {

public TabPerfil() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_perfil, container, false);

    Button btnPerfil = view.findViewById(R.id.btnPerfil);

    btnPerfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PerfilFragment fr= new PerfilFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tabFragment, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

**Fragmento que deveria reemplazar el principal:**

```
  public class PerfilFragment extends Fragment {

public PerfilFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);

    return view;
}
}
```

**Layout del fragmento principal:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tabFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TabsPrincipals.TabPerfil">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEconomia"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
        android:text="@string/txt_economia"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@drawable/txt_btn_login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnPerfil" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabelComanda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/txtLastComanda"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnEconomia" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listComanda"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtLabelComanda" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPerfil"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
        android:text="@string/btn_Perfil"
        android:textColor="@drawable/txt_btn_login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Xml de MainActivity:**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#B3D7D8"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Perfil" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Grup" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calendari" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Creo, que estas agregando tu fragment en el Layout del activity a traves del archivo xml, si es asi debes quitarlo y agregarlo en el metodo create del Activity, ya que los fragmentos que son agregados directamente en el xml, no se van con Transactions.<br> Lo comento, y no lo coloco como respuesta oficial porque no has publicado el Layout de tu Activity y es mas una corazonada

Comment: @Exodia he editado la pregunta añadiendo el xml de MainActivity. Gracias por tu aportación!